# How to Set Default Lazy Load Properties to Blog and Gallery Images on Wordpress Site

Tags: php, wordpress, lazy-loading

I'm using Enfold as my parent theme for my massive Wordpress site, so I can't go in and manually add lazy loading classes on each image and my company doesn't want to use a plugin for security reasons. Enfold's forum moderators gave me two filters to try in functions.php, but neither worked:

```
add_filter( 'wp_lazy_loading_enabled', __return_true, 999, 10 );
remove_filter( 'wp_img_tag_add_loading_attr', ['av_responsive_images', 'handler_wp_img_tag_add_loading_attr'], 99, 3 );
```

and

```
function ava_enable_lazyloading() {
    global $avia_config;
    $avia_config["alb_html_lazy_loading"] = "enabled"; 
}
add_action("get_header", "ava_enable_lazyloading");
```

How do I enable lazy-loading on images outside of the Advanced Layout Builder? Most of my slower pages are pulling images from blogs, galleries, or portfolio items, but they all seem to have a default class of avia-img-lazy-load-not- and then an id number for the image.

It’s frustrating that my blog and gallery images aren't lazy loading even though it's standard now with Wordpress's most recent updates.

I've also been digging in my theme folders in framework>php>class-responsive-images.php and in config-templatebuilder>avia-shortcodes>img>images.php with no luck.

Comment: “*It’s frustrating that my blog and gallery images aren't lazy loading even though it's standard now...*” That’s just what happens as technology improves, and Your company need to understand that code can become outdated just like hardware. The core WP code can offer new functionality, but themes and plugins are what implement that functionality on the site so they needs to be updated to use a feature such as lazy loading. But it’s just not feasible for most developers to upgrade all their existing themes every time a new feature is added to WP. Instead the feature is built into new themes

Comment: The theme has been updated to support lazy-loading, but not for gallery or blog images pulled remotely. These sites are *massive.* It'd take me years to move us to a newer theme. I'm the only developer.

Answer (score 0):

Native lazy loading is now a thing. You can simply add `loading="lazy"` to an `img` tag:

```
<img src="/path/to/image/elonmusk.png" loading="lazy" alt="Elon musk before/after">
```

You can learn more @ https://web.dev/native-lazy-loading/. Can I use for `loading="lazy"` @ https://caniuse.com/loading-lazy-attr (* Firefox only supports lazy loading for images)

Comment: This doesn't help me. My site is massive and has tens of thousands of images, all with different ids and classes, so I can't just write a plugin, either.

Comment: If you're using wordpress (you tagged it wordpress), then you're imgs are probably generated from a template, update that template with what I have put together and it should work